# Django: Passing DetailView pk to FormView

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I'm trying to create a modal form in a generic DetailView where user can make me aware of errors related to that specific object. When the form is submitted the user is supposed to return to the same page (the same DetailView) but I have problems figuring out how to pass the primary key to the success_url of the FormView.

`views.py`:

```
class ErrorView(AjaxTemplateMixin, FormView):
    form_class = ErrorForm
    template_name = 'app/error.html'

    def get_success_url(self, **kwargs):
        return reverse_lazy('feriehus_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})

    def form_valid(self, form):
       form_content = form.cleaned_data['content']

        template = get_template('error_template.txt')
        context = Context({
            'form_content': form_content
        })
        content = template.render(context)

        email = EmailMessage(
           'Fejl',
            content,
            'Your website ' + '',
           ['youremail@gmail.com']
        )
        email.send()
        return super(ErrorView, self).form_valid(form)

class FeriehusDetail(DetailView):
    model = Feriehus

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(FeriehusDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['price_data'] = CreateContext.price_time_serie(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return context
```

`urls.py`:

```
url(r'^error/$', views.ErrorView.as_view(), name='error'),
url(r'^feriehus/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.FeriehusDetail.as_view(), name='feriehus_detail'),
```

This part is not working:
`kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})`

Comment: First of all that's a view, not a form, so it should be in views.py. But you don't have anything that defines an object at all: you don't inherit from a view that knows about objects, just forms; and you don't do anything on form_valid to create an object by saving the form. So I don't know what object you could mean.

Comment: Thanks! That was a typo. It's fixed now. The form is inserted in the detailview template using `<a data-toggle="modal" href="{% url 'error' %}" data-target="#form-modal" class="btn border-white btn-lg"> Fejl i data?</a>` The detailview is describing an object and i want the success_url to return to the same page. I hope it makes more sense now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no FormView.object variable since this is just a **form** view. The view is about the form, and not about a single object manipulating.

You have to pass `pk` to that view somehow.

1. You can do this in url:

   ```
   url(r'^feriehus/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/error/$', views.ErrorView.as_view(), name='error')
   ```

   get_success_url:

   ```
   def get_success_url(self, **kwargs):
       return reverse_lazy('feriehus_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.kwargs['pk']})
   ```
2. Or you can pass `pk` in a query component of an url, so the url will look like this: `error/?pk=111`.

   get_success_url:

   ```
   def get_success_url(self, **kwargs):
       return reverse_lazy('feriehus_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.request.GET['pk']})
   ```
3. Finally, you can do it without any redirect at all, using a modal form like [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#live-demo).